# Splitting gravity along $x$, $y$, and $z$ axes

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, newtonian-gravity, acceleration

For my diploma project, I am building a posture correcting wearable, being able also to recognize some activities such as walking/running, climbing stairs, etc., and for this, I am using some accelerometers — two of them on the back.

Note: *As far as I could research on this, only using one accelerometer is not enough to split the forces on axes (to recognize the acceleration on each axis), because I need to know the angles it is tilted with, so that's why I am using two of them — one for computing the angles (calling it the **angle one**), the other one is using the angles from first and trying to compute the acceleration on each axis (**acceleration one**).*

Now I got to a point where the physics/mechanics and three dimensionality are messing with my calculations, and I cannot figure out if this one is correct:
[image]
If let's say I know the acceleration sensor is tilted (the green plane) with:

- $\alpha$ on $x$-axis;
- $\beta$ on $y$-axis;
- $\theta$ on $z$-axis

from the initial position ($\alpha = 0$, $\beta = 0$, and $\theta = 0$, parallel to the ground, and $z$ pointing toward the sky, the blue plane), could $g$ be written as
$$\vec{g} = g \left[\vec{\imath} \sin(\alpha) +\vec{\jmath}\sin(\beta) + \vec{k}\sin(\theta) \right].$$
Is this splitting of $\vec{g}$ among the axes correct, or have I missed anything?

Comment: Hi, you can use code formatting or math formatting to add clarity to your post. See help while [edit]ing for me details.

Comment: I think you are asking about converting between a direction vector, and Euler angles.  What research have you done and what concept do you need help with?

Comment: No, actually I got to convert the direction vectors into angles using the tangent between them. I have edited the post to be more explicit in what I need to compute.

Comment: Maybe you could add a crude sketch or some explanation to make clear what i, j and k are? Also, it is not clear to me why you need two accelerometers. If one of them can measure acceleration along three axes, then the full direction and magnitude of acceleration is known - in the reference frame of the accelerometer. If you know that the measured value is g, then that should be enough to determine how the accelerometer is rotated with respect to the vertical direction.

Comment: How exactly are the angles $\alpha$, $\beta$, and $\theta$ measured? Because this is not how orientations are described usually.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are asking is if you have a vector $\vec{g}$ defined in terms of the world directions $\hat{i}$, $\hat{j}$ and $\hat{k}$, how do you express this vector in the body directions $\hat{u}$, $\hat{v}$ and $\hat{w}$.

[image: fig1]

So in general you need the 3×3 rotation matrix $\mathrm{R}$ which has as columns the components of each $(\hat{u}, \hat{v}, \hat{w})$ expressed in the world coordinate.

$$ \mathrm{R} = \begin{Bmatrix} \hat{u} & \hat{v} & \hat{w} \end{Bmatrix} $$

This is often called the [direct cosine matrix](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/engineering/direction-cosine-matrix) and it allows body-to-world transformations such as

$$ \vec{g} = \mathrm{R} \, \vec{g}_{\rm body} $$

and since gravity is defined along the negative $\hat{k}$ direction, the body vector of gravity is

$$ \vec{g}_{\rm body} = \mathrm{R}^\top \vec{g} = \mathrm{R}^\top (- g\, \hat{k}) = (-g) \begin{pmatrix} \hat{k} \cdot \hat{u} \\ \hat{k} \cdot \hat{v}  \\ \hat{k} \cdot \hat{w} \end{pmatrix}  $$

<sub>Here $\mathrm{R}^\top$ is the transpose of the rotation matrix, which equals its inverse.</sub>

The reason this is the direct cosine matrix, is that each component above can be expressed from the consine of the angle the vectors make with each other

$$ \vec{g}_{\rm body} = (- g) \begin{pmatrix} \cos \theta_{\rm ku} \\ \cos \theta_{\rm kv} \\ \cos \theta_{\rm kw}\end{pmatrix} $$

where $\theta_{\rm k u}$ is the angle the $\hat{k}$ vector makes with the $\hat{u}$ vector, and so on with the remaining angles.

In your case, the angles $\alpha$, $\beta$, and $\theta$ are not well defined, and do not follow any standard representation of orientation that I know of. If they are indeed Euler angles, about the *x*, *y* and *z* axis then the orientation matrix is defined by a *sequence* of rotations

$$ \mathrm{R} = \mathrm{RX}(\alpha) \mathrm{RY}(\beta) \mathrm{RZ}(\theta)   $$

each about the rotated axis defined by the previous rotation, and the [elemental rotation matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Basic_rotations) in 3D ${\rm RX}$, ${\rm RY}$, ${\rm RZ}$ defined as usual.

If that is the case, then you still have $$ \vec{g}_{\rm body} = \mathrm{R}^\top \vec{g} $$ as your representation of gravity on the local directions.